# How to condense 'text' in x in if statement?

Tags: python

I have a code in which there is a line`if y in x or f in x or h in x` and so on. Even if it works,  it seems to be very long.
I tried `if (y or f or h) in x` and `if [y,f,h]in x` but nothing worked.
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Use `any` along with a *generator expression*:

```
y = 'y'
f = 'f'
x = 'x'

print(any(char in 'abcdex' for char in [y, f, x]))
```

Output:

```
True
```